# Having problems with using the mods button on the pip boy

Tags: pc, fallout-new-vegas

Can someone help me. I am unable to use the mod button on Fallout NV I have a non GRA mod and non GRA 357 magnum but whenever I use the X button nothing happens also it's not faded

Comment: I know of a repair button, but "mod"?

Comment: yeah there's a mod button

Comment: @Nolonar It does exist. You press x to mod your weapon by adding scopes, focus enhancers or other improved weapon parts

Comment: lb (xbox) x (pc)

Comment: Time to revisit NV, then ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the revolver in question:

[image: Fallout 357 revolver]

The Mod button is highlighted in the top right. When you press <kbd>X</kbd> the below menu should appear (forgive me for having only one mod, couldn't find another one).

[image: Mod menu]

When you click on a mod, it will be attached to a weapon (it will be noted with a "+" next to its name, and the attached mod will be listed in weapon's properties panel:

[image: Weapon with mod]

Make sure you have appropriate mod for a weapon - it's usually obvious from a mod's name which weapon it's for. Also, since you tagged this question as "pc", I assume you're pressing <kbd>X</kbd> on keyboard and not on a gamepad.

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember having to use the keyboard (maybe that's the problem; you can't), click on it with the mouse instead. Same goes for if you have a controller: try the mouse. Also, some guns will only take certain mods, and it's either a bug or something, that keeps *mod* lit up even though the mod won't go on it, as I've had that happen to me, too. I do however have a bunch of mod files installed, including Fallout3, in its entirety.

There's only two mods for the [357](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/.357_magnum_revolver) (falloutwikia):

> - .357 magnum revolver long barrel - increases the weapon's damage by 3.
> - .357 revolver heavy duty cylinder - increases the weapon's durability by 50%.

---

For GRA *Merged*: ([nexusmods.com](http://www.nexusmods.com/newvegas/mods/45111/?))

> All weapons have had their tags (GRA, Mad Bomber, etc) removed, and vanilla versions of weapons use the GRA weapon mods instead.

Comment: I have tried but whenever I try to go to the (X) mod button it deselects the weapon

Comment: @user127062 Sounds like a mod conflict, or you have GRA *Merged* installed, see edit.

Comment: I will take a look

Answer (score 0):

It's <kbd>Page Up</kbd>. After a firm hand on the keyboard and swiping left and right, finally figured it out.